# Can I see the IP address of the host in the Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, ip, port, host

I used the Docker command to run a container.

```
docker run -itd -p 8001:801 --name centos7_01 centos:centos7 /bin/bash
```

1. Can I see the IP address of the host in the container?
2. Can I write the port of the host in the port map consistent with the port of the container?

Comment: you can see the IP address of the host in the container by running the command "ip addr show" within the container

Comment: you can pass the host IP as environment to container `docker run --env HST="$(hostname -i)"`.

Comment: You usually don't need it, and it may be tricky to find it (for example on Docker Desktop).  I've linked to a question that describes a couple of approaches, but if you're just trying to make a call to a non-container process, see the question that one is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The host is the host machine that you run docker on. There is no host in the container. The host *runs* the container(s), i.e. the containers run *on* the host.

The ports are `HOST:CONTAINER`.